# how do i make this fit to my page as it look small in size

Tags: html, css, image, size

what am i missing it look small in my webpage i want this to be on my whole screen. i cant find where i am getting wrong. i want this to fit all size of pc,tv,4k,laptop screen.
[it look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIU3G.jpg)

```css
.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.container .box .thumb{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .box:nth-child(odd) .thumb {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box .thumb img{
    width: 100%;
}
.container .box .details{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #262626;
}
.container .box:nth-child(even) .details {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box:nth-child(1) .details {
    background: #65214a;
}
.container .box:nth-child(2) .details {
    background: #fd3f41;
}
.container .box:nth-child(3) .details {
    background: #ffb539;
}
.container .box .details .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% + 16px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover .details .content{
    top: calc(50%);
}
.container .box .details .content h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.container .box .details .content a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.container .box:hover .details .content a{
    transform: scale(1);
}
.container .box .details .content a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #262626;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="activity.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

what am i missing it look small in my webpage i want this to be on my whole screen. i cant find where i am getting wrong. i want this to fit all size of pc,tv,4k,laptop screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you were using a fixed `width: 250px;` on your child. The `box class`. I went ahead and changed the `width to 33.33%` to align with the three boxes you currently have. This way it has each **box-column** split into **33.33%** of the **100% standard width** of any device.

```css
.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
.container .box{
    position: relative;
    width: 33.33%; /*Change Applied*/
    height: 500px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.container .box .thumb{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container .box:nth-child(odd) .thumb {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box .thumb img{
    width: 100%;
}
.container .box .details{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #262626;
}
.container .box:nth-child(even) .details {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container .box:nth-child(1) .details {
    background: #65214a;
}
.container .box:nth-child(2) .details {
    background: #fd3f41;
}
.container .box:nth-child(3) .details {
    background: #ffb539;
}
.container .box .details .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% + 16px);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .box:hover .details .content{
    top: calc(50%);
}
.container .box .details .content h3{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.container .box .details .content a{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.container .box:hover .details .content a{
    transform: scale(1);
}
.container .box .details .content a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #262626;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="activity.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81z07Nvam1L._SL1500_.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <div class="content">
                    <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="">
                    <h3>Desert Safari</h3>
                    <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you can show me how will i add link to each container that will be helpful
i don't want link on read more i want on whole box

Comment: @MSameerAsif You can wrap anchor tags `<a href="#"></a>` around your `<div class="details">` like so: `<a href="#"><div class="details"></a>` and also around your img like so. `<a href="#"><img src="/images/facebook.png" alt=""></a>` Because there are two separate child containers in each 1/3 of content you will have to link them individually, but if you give them the same link it will act the same.